# Unable to destroy gameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to destroy a gameObject once it has collided with two other objects with the following code but it does not work.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Sphere" && col.gameObject.tag == "Pyramid")
    {
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("Pentagon"));
    }
}
```

Can someone offer a correction of my code because I can't seem to figure out how to destroy my "Pentagon"?

Comment: first of all it should be `Destroy (gameObject);`, but why are you trying to access the `gameObject.transform` after trying to destroy it??? what are you trying to do exactly? What script is attached to what object here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your first line:

```
 if (col.gameObject.tag == "Sphere" && col.gameObject.tag == "Pyramid")
```

You cant have 2 tags on a gameObject. I assume what you want to say is || instead of &&.

What are you trying to achieve in that second block of code? Instead of deleting the rigidbody, maybe just set RigidBody.Enabled = false.

Comment: @Anonymous: They've changed the API recently. Try `GetComponent<RigidBody>().Enabled = false`.

Comment: Is the second block of code in the Pentagon object? If it is, its probably because its been deleted.